# Подсчёт количества продуктов, входящих в две категории

Tags: mysql

В таблице `product_filter` есть два столбца: `product_id` и `filter_id`. Нужно получить количество `product_id`, для которых есть запись `filter_id = 1` и `filter_id = 5`.
Как это сделать?

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста: должны присутствовать **и** строка с *filter_id = 1*, **и** строка с *filter_id = 5*?

Comment: да, и filter_id = 1, и filter_id = 5

Comment: если есть две записи (с одним и тем же product_id), в которых *filter_id = 1*, и одна запись (всё с тем же product_id), в которой *filter_id = 5*, то какой результат мы должны получить? 1, 2 или 3?

Comment: задача в том, чтобы получить количество product_id, для которых есть filter_id = 1 и filter_id = 5. Иными словами, надо знать количество продуктов, у которых есть два фильтра с ИД 1 и 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в первом запросе выводятся сами строки, подпадающие под условие (наличие **и** строки с *f=1* **и** строки с *f=5*).

второй запрос — подсчёт количества строк вложенного запроса (вложенный запрос идентичен первому).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/876f0/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (p int, f int);

insert into t values
   (1, 1)
  ,(2, 1)
  ,(1, 5)
  ,(3, 1)
  ,(4, 5)
  ,(1, 1)
  ,(2, 5)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from t as t1
join t as t2
  on t1.p = t2.p
where t1.f = 1 and t2.f = 5
group by t1.p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/876f0/1/0)**:

```
| p | f | p | f |
|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select count(*) from
(
  select t1.p
  from t as t1
  join t as t2
    on t1.p = t2.p
  where t1.f = 1 and t2.f = 5
  group by t1.p
) as t0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/876f0/1/1)**:

```
| count(*) |
|----------|
|        2 |
```

Comment: `select count(distinct t1.p)
    from t as t1,t as t2
   where t1.f = 1 and t2.f = 5 and t1.p = t2.p`

Comment: @Mike, да, так ещё короче. напишите и свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Подойдет?

```
SELECT product_id
FROM product_filter
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING FIND_IN_SET(1, GROUP_CONCAT(filter_id))>0 
    AND FIND_IN_SET(5, GROUP_CONCAT(filter_id))>0
```

Ну или такой вариант:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM product_filter
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING CONCAT(',', GROUP_CONCAT(filter_id), ',') REGEXP ',1,' =1
    AND CONCAT(',', GROUP_CONCAT(filter_id), ',') REGEXP ',5,' =1;
```

Оба запроса вернут список `product_id` - останется лишь посчитать кол-во строк.

Почему не подходит?

Comment: не слишком ли сложная конструкция? мне кажется, с join-ом как-то проще получается (см. мой ответ).

Comment: Ну тут вообще что то страшное. А если у меня 1 млн записей в базе и из них только 10 штук с filter_id 1 и 5. Во первых запрос в любом случае перероет всю таблицу, даже если по filter_id есть индексы. Во вторых group_concat переполнится (там же ограничение 1024 байта на собранную строку) и в итоге будет неопределенное поведение

Comment: @Mike и Alexander - да, согласен.. :) с обоими. Автор, поменяйте галочку на ответ Александра, пожалуйста. Он единственный правильный. Или может модераторы это могут сделать?

Answer (score -2):

SELECT COUNT('product_id .product_id') FROM product_filter WHERE filter_id = 1 and filter_id = 5

[image: пример в phpmyadmin проверил на др базе]

Comment: что-то вы совсем не то делаете. и почему-то скрин расходится с запросом в ответе))

Comment: На скрине такой же запрос из моей таблицы, вернул кол-во по условию