# Как правильно формировать criteria для связи HAS_MANY?

Tags: php, yii

Есть модель POST. И есть модель category_r
В последней 3 столбца:
id, Post_id, category_id.

Мне нужно сделать выборку постов, где category_id равна 1 и 2, к примеру.
ВОт моя criteria:

```
$criteria->condition = 'category.category_id=2 AND category.category_id=1';
```

Выдает ошибку в sql-запросе, Если добавить `$criteria->together = true;`,
то возвращает пустую модель.

С одним условием, например:

```
criteria->condition = 'category.category_id=2' - тут все отлично.
```

Что не так делаю?

Comment: возможный дубликат: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/483108/178576

Comment: Я думаю вам стоит обязательно поместить в вопрос полностью запрос который совершаете. А также показать модели с их связями (relations).... А также сказать зачем вы указываете имя таблицы через точку, если оно передается через модель либо непосредственно в коде.. Еще один вопрос... как связана модель `category_r` и то, что вы выбираете из таблицы `category` ?? ...И еще, возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону `addCondition` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail

Answer (score 1):

В одной и то же записи не может быть и `category_id=2` и `category_id=1`, используйте `OR`

```
$criteria->condition = 'category.category_id=2 OR category.category_id=1';
```

После дополнительной информации:

Можно использовать подзапрос (т.к. нет понимая вашей структуры то код примерный)

```
$cat = Category::model();
$sub_query = new CDbCriteria();
$sub_query->select = ['post_id'];
$sub_query->addCondition('category_id = 1 OR category_id = 2');
$sub_query->group = 'post_id';
$sub_query->having = 'COUNT(post_id) = 2';
$sub_query = $cat->getCommandBuilder()->createFindCommand($cat->getTableSchema(),$sub_query)->getText();

$posts = new CDbCriteria();
$posts->addCondition('id IN ('.$sub_query.')');
$posts->params = [':sub_query'=>$sub_query];
$events = Post::model()->findAll($posts);
```

Ну или без второй критерии:

```
$sub_query = 'SELECT post_id FROM '.Category::model()->tableName().' WHERE category_id = 1 OR category_id = 2 GROUP BY post_id HAVING COUNT(post_id) = 2';
$posts = new CDbCriteria();
$posts->addCondition('id IN ('.$sub_query.')');
$posts->params = [':sub_query'=>$sub_query];
$events = Post::model()->findAll($posts);
```

Можно использовать вариант который по ссылке которую вам написали в комментариях:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = ['*', 'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category.category_id  SEPARATOR ",") as cat_id '];
$criteria->with = ['category'];
$criteria->group = 't.id';
$criteria->having = 'cat_id REGEXP "1" = 1 AND cat_id REGEXP "2" = 1';
Post::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Ну или вот так:

```
$category_table = Category::model()->tableName();
$posts = new CDbCriteria();
$posts->join = 'LEFT JOIN '.$category_table.' as cat_1 ON t.id = cat_1.post_id AND cat_1.category_id=1 '.
               'LEFT JOIN '.$category_table.' as cat_2 ON t.id = cat_2.post_id AND cat_2.category_id=2 ';
$posts->condition = 'cat_1.post_id = t.id AND cat_2.post_id = t.id ';
```

Вы просто должны понимать что если вы будите пытаться так же выбрать данные из таблицы category_r (category_id = 1 AND category_id = 2), то ничего вы не получите, так как в одной записи только одно значение category_id, то же самое происходит когда вы используете JOIN. На основе этого вы можете пробовать строить свои запросы.

Comment: Может я не совсем понятно обьяснил. У записи пост, есть много записей в таблице category_r. Связь типа Has_many. Так вот, мне нужно выбрать все Посты, где в таблице  category_r столбец category_id =1 и 2

Comment: Я обновил ответ